# Как сделать регистрацию на сайте?

Tags: javascript, php, python, html, css

Я даже не знаю как загуглить то, что мне нужно конкретно. Буду рад, если поможете. В общем, как сделать обычную регистрацию, я понимаю. Делаем базу данных, форму, затем делаем запросы и информация с сайта подтягивается в базу. Но если тебе нужно сделать сайт с личной библиотекой, где разные пользователи видят разный контент, как это организовать? Например, пользователь А добавляет свои книжки в блокнот, а пользователь Б - свои. И никто другого контента не видит. Я не требую конкретного ответа и решения, но я правда не знаю как найти информацию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого нужна отдельная таблица где будут храниться блокноты.
Например :

```
Таблица Favorites
user_id | book_id
A       |1
A       |2
A       |3
B       |4
B       |5
```

Теперь на странице, где будут видны сохранённые блокноты, вы сделаете вот такой запрос к БД

```
SELECT Books.book_name, Books.book_description FROM Books
INNER JOIN Favorites
ON Favorites.book_id = Books.id
WHERE Books.user_id = $id
```

где $id это идентификационный номер зарегистрированного/авторизованного пользователя, и результат уже публикуйте на страницу.
Наверное так (・ω・)